# simplifying an integration of partial derivative with respect to different variable

Tags: real-analysis, integration, partial-differential-equations, definite-integrals

Let $u(x,t)$ be a square integrable function defined over $]0,a[ \times ]0,T[$. 
I want to simplify these two expressions : 
$$\int _0 ^a \frac{\partial ^2 u(x,t)}{\partial t ^2 }.u(x,t) \, dx$$ and
$$\int _0 ^a \frac{\partial u(x,t)}{\partial t}.u(x,t) \, dx$$

I wanted to use Leibniz integral rule to move the partial derivative outside the integral but it didn't seem right. 
Any other thoughts ?

Comment: What is your goal, where do you want to get to?

Comment: @HyperbolicPDEfriend I have an IVBP and I want to find an estimation for those expressions.

Comment: @HyperbolicPDEfriend Something like here in page 4 https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~hunter/pdes/ch6.pdf 
I don't have exactly the same equation but I don't understand how the expression was found.

Comment: Even under the hypothesis of some theorem that let you swap integral and derivative, you still can't, since $$\int _0 ^a \frac{\partial u(x,t)}{\partial t}.u(x,t) \, dx\neq\frac{\partial}{\partial t} \int _0 ^a u(x,t)\,u(x,t) \, dx = \int _0 ^a \frac{\partial}{\partial t}\left(u(x,t)\,u(x,t)\right) \, dx$$

Comment: However, i notice that, at least for the second equation you have written, it is worth noticing that $$u\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}=\frac{\partial}{\partial t} \left(\frac{u^2}{2}\right)$$

Comment: @Davide Thank you, this one helps a lot !